# Add item to existing Matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Given the following setup:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], label='linear')
ax.plot([0,1,4,9,16,25,36], label='square')
lgd = ax.legend(loc='lower right')
```

If a function `add_patch` receives only `lgd` as an argument, can a custom legend item be added to the legend on top of the existing items, without changing the other properties of the legend?

I was able to add an item using:

```
def add_patch(legend):
    from matplotlib.patches import Patch
    ax = legend.axes
    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles.append(Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r'))
    labels.append("Color Patch")
    ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
```

But this does not preserve the properties of the legend like location. How can I add an item given only the legend object after lines have been plotted?

Answer (score 19):

In principle a legend is not meant to be updated, but recreated instead.

The following would do what you're after, but beware that this is a hack which uses internal methods and is hence not guaranteed to work and might break in future releases. So don't use it in production code. Also, if you have set a title to the legend with a different font(size) than default, it will be lost upon updating. Also, if you have manipulated the order of handles and labels via `markerfirst`, this will be lost upon updating.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], label='linear')
ax.plot([0,1,4,9,16,25,36], label='square')
lgd = ax.legend(loc='lower right')

def add_patch(legend):
    from matplotlib.patches import Patch
    ax = legend.axes

    handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
    handles.append(Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r'))
    labels.append("Color Patch")

    legend._legend_box = None
    legend._init_legend_box(handles, labels)
    legend._set_loc(legend._loc)
    legend.set_title(legend.get_title().get_text())


add_patch(lgd)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Is adding the color patch after the lines have been plotted but before adding the legend an option?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1 = ax.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], label='linear')
line2 = ax.plot([0,1,4,9,16,25,36], label='square')
patch = Patch(facecolor='orange', edgecolor='r', label='Color patch')
lgd = ax.legend(handles=[line1, line2, patch], loc='lower right')
```

Comment: I get a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_label'` error. Possibly because `line1` and `line2` has no associated `get_label` method.

Comment: Evidently, the behavior of `ax.plot()` has now been changed so it returns a list (with in this case just one element). So the last line will have to be `lgd = ax.legend(handles=[line1[0], line2[0], patch], loc='lower right')`